# Why $ _ does not return the complete object

Tags: powershell, oop

I'm a beginner in powershell, I've been using it for just a few weeks, I was thinking about $_ when I saw this:

Get-ChildItem should return the files on a directory

```
PS C:\Users\Edu-mat\Powershell> Get-ChildItem


    Diretório: C:\Users\Edu-mat\Powershell


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       10/08/2018     13:38              7 Test0.txt
-a----       10/08/2018     13:42              5 Test1.txt
-a----       10/08/2018     13:42              7 Test2.txt
-a----       10/08/2018     13:43              8 Test3.txt
```

$_ Means current object in the pipeline.

but when i did `Get-ChildItem | %{write-host $_}` the output was not as expected

```
PS C:\Users\Edu-mat\Powershell> Get-ChildItem | %{write-host $_}
Test0.txt
Test1.txt
Test2.txt
Test3.txt
```

WHY $_ is not returning the entire object, it just printing the name of the file ?

can someone please explain me.

Comment: Your first example does not show the entire object either, it is missing the creation date, the full directory name, all the NoteProperties like `PSIsContainer`, all the methods, the ScriptProperties... objects don't fit on the screen, you can't see them, you can only turn parts of them into text and show that. The PowerShell output formatters do it one way, to try to look like the old Command Prompt `dir` command, `write-host` does it another way which is from the .Net framework beneath PowerShell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$_` is returning the entire object, however `Write-Host` expects a string, and so the `.ToString()` method is called on the object.  In the case of `System.IO.FileInfo` its `ToString()` is overridden to output the name of the file.

Try this and see for yourself:

`Get-ChildItem | %{Write-Host $_.ToString()}`

`Get-ChildItem | %{Write-Host $_.GetType()}`

`Get-ChildItem | %{Write-Host $_.Mode}`

Answer (score 4):

`Write-Host` is for writing information out to the console, so objects are formatted as strings, similar to if you had done `gci | % { "$_" }` (except the latter writes to the output stream not directly to the host).

If you want to write directly to the console but the same formatting you would see if sent to the console implicitly, use `Out-Host` as recommended by [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0):

```
Get-ChildItem | Out-Host
```

His comment in full:

> I suggest using `Out-Host` directly; also, perhaps surprisingly,
>   `Write-Host "$_"` is not always the same as `Write-Host $_`, because the
>   latter results in `.ToString()` getting called, which defaults to a
>   culture-sensitive representation (where available), whereas
>   PowerShell's string interpolation by design always uses the invariant
>   culture